# Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax in a MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I'm reading the book MySQL from Paul DuBois, and I'm following precisely how to do subqueries. I don't know if the logic of my query is correct, but I imagined that my syntax was correct.

Anyway, I keep getting this error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE userID = (SELECT userID FROM usuarios WHERE deprecated_userName = 'webmast' at line 2

For this query:

```
INSERT INTO cursosUsuarios (deprecated_cursoID, userID) VALUES (4255, 1)
WHERE userID = (SELECT userID FROM usuarios WHERE deprecated_userName = 'webmaster');
```

Is there something very obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: The correct syntax is INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);

Comment: Plain insert statement does not have a where clause. Insert ... select ... statement may have one in the select part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain `insert` statement does not have a `where` clause. `Insert ... select ...` statement may have one in the select part.

I assume you would like to sign up your `webmaster` user to a course. I would use the `insert ... select ...` in this case:

```
INSERT INTO cursosUsuarios (deprecated_cursoID, userID)
SELECT 4255, userID
FROM usuarios
WHERE deprecated_userName = 'webmaster'
```

Comment: Thank for your answer!! One question: 4255 is the deprecated_cursoID value, should I still use it a select statement like that? (...SELECT 4255 userID...). Again, thank you for your help. I just realized that the examples in the book were made with select statements with subqueries.

Comment: Oops, missed a comma between 4255 and userID. Updated the answer